# How can I remove the row with "*" in R program?

Tags: r, symbols

I want to remove the row that missing the value. For example I have data frame look like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Lunch","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner")),
  total_bill = c(12.75,14.89,"*",17.23)
)
```

I want to remove the column Lunch with value *. What should I do? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `subset` with `!=`

```
dat1 <- droplevels(subset(dat, total_bill != "*"))
dat1 <- type.convert(dat1, as.is = TRUE)
sum(dat1$total_bill, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 44.87
```

Comment: Yes it worked but how can we use the new dataframe after removing it? because when I deal with function like sum(dat$total_bill) it still got the error.

Comment: Yes I voted up but my reputation is low :( so It told me like that :(

Answer (score 0):

If `total_bill` is character, you can convert it to numeric which will turn all non-characters to `NA` automatically with a warning message and then you can perform `sum`, `mean` or other mathematical operations on it.

```
sum(as.numeric(dat$total_bill),na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 44.87
```

If `total_bill` is factor, you need to use

```
sum(as.numeric(as.character(dat$total_bill)),na.rm = TRUE)
```